# C# DateTime Math - Crossing into Previous Months

Tags: c#, datetime

I just discovered a DateTime math bug in my code today, August 1st, the start of a new month.
I am setting a DateTime class member to the DateTime value of 7 days ago. So the value it should have on August 1st, would be July 25th

I clearly see the problem when trying to subtract 7 from 1 (DateTime.Now.Day-7).

So how do I create a DateTime object that always works regardless of what day of the month it is?

**Error:**

```
Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
```

Here is the code:

```
DateFrom = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day-7));
```

What is the correct way to set this member to be 7 days ago from current DateTime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just subtract seven days from `DateTime.Now`:

```
DateFrom = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
```

Comment: Perfect. thanks, Andrei. Will accept your answer as soon as SO will allow

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFrom date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method of datetime object that takes integer. As it takes negative values as well so you can easily move back in time.

```
DateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
```